# Git get latest commit after reset -hard

Tags: git-reset

I did a git reset -hard FETCH_HEAD before and I can't figure out to get back to my latest commit.

```
HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to adding_events
HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from adding_events to master
HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to adding_events
HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from 3458u9qfhaushf
HEAD@{4}: commit: Testing Gemfile edit
HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from master to fajesnfkj24b
HEAD@{6}: commit: Changed Gemfile after reset
HEAD@{7}: reset: moving to FETCH_HEAD
HEAD@{8}: commit: Added Event Show page, Upload Event Pic
HEAD@{9}: commit: Add Category Database and Event pages
HEAD@{10}: merge adding_events: Fast-forward
HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from adding_events to master
HEAD@{12}: commit: Replaced Post with Events
```

When I do git status on my master branch this is what comes up

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 5 different commits each, respectively.
```

When I open the app in my directory the 12 commit "Replaced Post with Events" is the latest file shown.  I'd like to get back to my last commit of 8 "Added the event Show page, Upload Event Pic"...any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{8}
```

to reset the current branch pointer to that specific commit.

Comment: it moved me to
    "HEAD is now at 6ed2d19 Fix a test". Should i do FETCH_HEAD instead?

Comment: Well the name `HEAD@{8}` depends on which is the 8th entry in the reflog for your current branch head (which moves every time the reflog is updated). The `git reflog` command normally shows the commit ID in the left hand column (which appears to be omitted from your original post), I suggest using the commit ID directly to avoid confusion.